# Which file format is commonly used for custom-made cabling?

Tags: cable-assemblies, fritzing

I'm in the situation to need custom-made cabling to connect my Raspi to a bunch of peripherals. I used Fritzing to design the cable harness (see the rendering below),…

[image: Cable harness designed in Fritzing]

… but apparently, my favorite electronics shop (where custom-made cabling is available) doesn't even know what Fritzing is, so I must find a file format suitable for describing cabling, which is commonly used in the industry AND supported by Fritzing as an export data format. The guy from the shop suggested MS Word (!!), but I don't think this is a serious answer.

Here ist the link to the original Fritzing file: [Kabelbaum Raspi.fzz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_oVLHUx9M4xUXUJgyq-ja5ufmp5cVdw/view?usp=share_link)

So: Are there any file formats, which meet these requirements?

Comment: If they said Word they probably just need something human viewable.  PDF or OpenDocument Text should be fine.

Comment: There are numerous issues with your diagram: it's messy, cable length is missing from many of the cables, no connectors are specified, etc

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but Fritzing isn't a serious piece of software that fulfils the need to specify how a custom cable should be made. On the other hand Microsoft word is an eminently suitable means of making such a drawing (although there are alternatives like TinyCad that can do a better job). Your Fritzing diagram is totally unfathomable to me but like I said, don't take this the wrong way. Each to their own.

Comment: For a one-of (or even  few), I'd make it myself.  You may have to invest a small amount in crimping tools, but you wouldn't have to document it well enough for someone else to make it.

Comment: Did the person from the manufacturer maybe simply ask for you to deliver a table that lists what is connected to what? I can't do anything with your fritzing diagram, but if you have me a table that said "main connector on 6 to audio connector pin 3, main connector pin 7 to power connector pin 1, main connector pin 8 to audio connector pin 2", I could actually understand what you want. Add a column for length, color, amperage of necessary, and you'd have a useful description.

Comment: Another remark: there's things that don't look very sane here. As a general rule of thumb, to every external signal that you deliver as single conductor, you will need to know the ground potential, so that you can make sense of the signal if it is a voltage signal, or a current return path, if it is a current signal. For that reason, you would probably never have just a single cable going somewhere, but always at least a ground connection, too.

Comment: @OskarSkog You don't see the length & connector data in this rendering, but they are stored in the Fritzing file itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, they did not ask me for a pinout, but I do have an Excel list with descriptions of all pins and connectors (which is, in fact, even older than the Fritzing schema).

Comment: Honestly the fritzing scheme contains no useful additional information as far as I could tell. Do they not want your excel sheet?

Comment: I've just linked the original Fritzing file in this question. See above. Of course it contains more info than its rendering.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of relatively expensive (thousands of dollars up) software packages and add-ons for already expensive MCAD (mechanical CAD) packages that purport to make this easy. Having evaluated and a number of them (we eventually bought one), they all are also costly in learning curve and may not have as adequate a library of connectors as you might hope for. Some even create a computer analog of the “nailboard” harness physical method, which is pretty cool.

For small scale, I would suggest just making a conventional draftsman-like 2D mechanical drawing of the cable, and deal with connectivity manually.  Just use whatever mechanical CAD package you are comfortable with, and send them a .pdf with a nice title block and so on. Don’t forget to specify connector manufacturers, part numbers, wire gauges, insulation ratings, required approvals, colors, dimensions and tolerances, and any additional details such as overbraid or shrink tubing, and the specifications for those. However even a carefully created hand drawn sketch would be better than the Fritzing thing, provided all the necessary information is there.

On the other hand, don’t over-specify- if a generic material or part will do (perhaps with caveats), no point in rigidly specifying something that may not be in their inventory.

[Here](https://wiring-harness.com/considerations-when-drawing-a-wire-harness/) are some recommendations from a commercial cable manufacturer, and an example of what they expect to see:

[image]

Comment: Yes, sure, this is the way professionals do it. But for me, a simpler solution would work, too.

Answer (score 2):

An [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cable+harness+wiring+diagram) will show up plenty of methods.

[image]

*Figure 1. A particularly nice way to make up the harnesses - similar to those used in the auto industry. Image source: [Altium](https://resources.altium.com/p/how-to-use-schematic-cad-drawings-for-cable-assemblies-part-4).*

Your drawing should show connector types, pin numbers, male/female, cable size, color, gauge, length, etc.

Comment: OK, connector types, genders, and colors are already visible in the Fritzing file, and for the gauge, I simply measured a similar stock cable.